# Strange behaviour with string.include? in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string

I do not understand why `include?` is returning `true` in both the cases. Can someone enlighten me?

```
"".include?("") # => true
"stackoverflow".include?("") # => true
```

The [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-include-3F) states:

```
include? other_str → true or false
Returns true if str contains the given string or character.
```

Comment: It's like in set theory: the empty set is subset of any other set (including the empty set itself).

Comment: I think `"stackoverflow".include?("")` should give `false`..This is a bug..Otherwise `"stackoverflow".count('')` shouldn't give `0`.

Answer (score 7):

Because string "stackoverflow" contains an infinite number of empty strings between the letters/characters.

Comment: Your answer is correct...but `"stackoverflow".count('') # 0`.. so something odd...so it should goes to bug tracker..

Comment: Do you have idea whether that infinite number is aleph-0 (cardinality of integers), or aleph-1 (cardinality of rational numbers), or something larger?

Comment: @sawa: well, it's *infinitely* large. How can one infinity be larger than another? :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev When there is leftover in set A no matter how you do a one-to-one mapping from A to B, then A is larger than another. Since you mentioned infinity, I was curious which infinity you meant.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, there are an infinite number of distinct infinite numbers. This is strange, but true. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georg_Cantor for the story of the man who proved this fact.

Answer (score 1):

This not a bug. `count` and `include?` work very differently. `include?` checks for substrings, but the description of `count` says

> [Each parameter] defines a set of characters to count. The
>   intersection of these sets defines the characters to count in str.

By providing only the empty string as a parameter you are telling `count` to not count any characters. The only sensible thing for it to return in such a case is 0.

Comment: Should've been a comment.